# Python: split string and get position

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a string into pieces and want to get additional the (starting) positions of the splitted pieces of the string.

I can do this with the following code:

```
str_ = '  d     A7    g7'
flag_non_space_string_started = False
positions = []
for i, letter in enumerate(str_):
    if letter is not ' ':
        if not flag_non_space_string_started:
            positions.append(i)
            flag_non_space_string_started = True
    else:
        flag_non_space_string_started = False
# this is what I want
print(str_.split())
print(positions)
# prints:
# ['d', 'A7', 'g7']
# [2, 8, 14]
```

Is there a shorter (more pythonic) way to get the positions?

Comment: Shorter is not the same as pythonic. Often, shortening is bad, since your code becomes harder to understand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506563/what-is-the-pythonic-way-of-programming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html%23itertools.groupby) with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html%23enumerate) here. Here we are grouping the item at white spaces using `not str.isspace`, so `k` will be True for non-whitespace characters and False for white spaces, hence the `if k` condition. Now as each group is an iterator we need to call next() on it to get the starting index as well as the first character. Now to get the rest of the group items use a list-comprehension and pass it to str.join to get a string. Don't forget to prepend the item we popped earlier to this string:

```
from itertools import groupby

str_ = '  d     A7    g7'

for k, g in groupby(enumerate(str_), lambda x: not x[1].isspace()):
    if k:
        pos, first_item = next(g)
        print pos, first_item + ''.join([x for _, x in g])
```

Output:

```
2 d
8 A7
14 g7
```

If the above solution seems complicated, then one can also use re.finditer. The match objects returned by re.finditer have methods like .start() and group(), they correspond to the start index of the matched group and the group itself respectively.

```
import re

str_ = '  d     A7    g7'

for m in re.finditer(r'\S+', str_):
    index, item = m.start(), m.group()
    # now do something with index, item
```

Comment: Isn't this code more complex, therefore not pythonic?

Comment: @user5061 I personally don't find it complicated, I am simply taking the advantage of tools provided by Python. Anyways added another solution.

Comment: The OP seems to actually wants two separate lists so there is more work than just `re.finditer`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The more is simply a zip* call.

Comment: How will zip* create two lists? A simple for loop and append would work just fine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Indices, items = map(list, zip(*LC)), or a simple loop over re.finditer followed by append calls to two lists will also do. Let's leave that exercise for OP.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Nothing personal contrary to what you believe. Only reason i downvoted is because it  proliferates the impression that "short, complex code, is good code".

Comment: @user5061 Why do you think it was me who downvoted? o.O

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I apologize for my assumption. Edited my comment  (and will delete this one as well, since it's too chatty). Also, since your second solution is clear and you include a notice about complexity i will revert my vote.